# Finding the complex function from its real and imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider a complex number in rectangular form, i.e. $z=x+iy$. If I am given the real part and imaginary part of the function, take $z^2$ as an example, i.e. $f(z)=z^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)$. Is it possible for me to have a systematic way to find out the original function? (i.e. $f(z)=z^2$)

I don't know whether it is a silly question, or the answer can be found easily from google. So any related link or generous response will mean a lot to me!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're supposing we know *both* the real and imaginary parts?

Comment: yes. Both of them are known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute
$$x=\frac{z+\bar z}{2},\quad y=\frac{z-\bar z}{2\,i}.$$
If everything is alright, the terms in $\bar z$ should disappear.